# Is it possible for Logback to read logger parameters?

Tags: java, logging, logback

In logback I configured my logback.xml file to separate debug and error log lines in separate files, respectively, debug.log and error.log.

The idea with the parameters would be to create something like:

```
logger.error("A new error occured with a param", 1);
```

Where 1 would be an integer passed to the logger that should be written to error.log like:

```
11:22:17.678 [main] ERROR c.j.example.logbackmavenexample.App - A new error occured with a param - 1
```

My logback.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- System.out Appender -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

   <appender name="debugFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/Users/henriqueferreira/Desktop/separate-log/debug.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%ex{full}</pattern>
        </encoder>
   </appender>

   <appender name="errorFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
      <File>/Users/henriqueferreira/Desktop/separate-log/error.log</File>
           <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>ERROR</level>
                <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
           </filter>
      <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%ex{full}</pattern>
      </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG"><!-- Using the lowest level here -->
      <appender-ref ref="debugFile" />
      <appender-ref ref="errorFile" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**Is it possible to write that passed parameter in the created log file?**

Comment: what's wrong with writing `logger.error("A new error occured with a param -
 1")` or `logger.error("A new error occured with a param - {}", 1)`

Comment: @Bentaye The next step is to use that parameter as an additional filtering mechanism so it's preferable to have it as it is (a parameter).

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about it, but I know you can use Markers (`org.slf4j.Marker`) for additional filtering. I don't know how to use them or if that would help your problem but you still can have a look.

Comment: @Bentaye thank you I will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bentaye I was able to find the answer. Basically instead of passing the integer as a parameter I can pass a Marker such as:

```
Marker interesting = MarkerFactory.getMarker("INTERESTING");
logger.debug(interesting, "something happened");
```

and it will log as I wanted:

```
12:37:59.060 [main] DEBUG c.j.example.logbackmavenexample.App - INTERESTING - something happened
```

I just had to add %marker in the pattern of this file in the logback.xml file:

```
<encoder>
    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %marker - %msg%n%ex{full}</pattern>
</encoder>
```